# Least common upper class of DecisionTreeRegressor and RandomForestRegressor

Tags: scala, apache-spark-mllib, type-parameter

I want to create a method that will return one of these two types:

```
 - org.apache.spark.ml.regression.DecisionTreeRegressor
 - org.apache.spark.ml.regression.RandomForestRegressor
```

What will be the return type of this method?  I believe that it will have a return type of

```
 - org.apache.spark.ml.Estimator<M>
```

but I don't know what the type parameter `M` should be.

If I simply do this (for example):

```
  def getRegressor(): org.apache.spark.ml.Estimator = {
    new DecisionTreeRegressor()
      .setLabelCol("label")
      .setFeaturesCol("features")
      .setMaxBins(100)
  }
```

I get the following error:

> class Estimator takes type parameters

Comment: You can ignore the parameter type using underscore

Comment: hey @paul-reiners. How did you manage to solve the problem? What is the way to return a generic Estimator and be able to pass it into methods as a parameter?

Answer (score 2):

Just ignore the type by using `_` (underscore) If you don't care about it.

```
def getRegressor(): org.apache.spark.ml.Estimator[_] = {
    new DecisionTreeRegressor()
      .setLabelCol("label")
      .setFeaturesCol("features")
      .setMaxBins(100)
  }
```

I think the type should be `DecisionTreeRegressionModel`

```
 def getRegressor(): org.apache.spark.ml.Estimator[DecisionTreeRegressionModel] = {
    new DecisionTreeRegressor()
      .setLabelCol("label")
      .setFeaturesCol("features")
      .setMaxBins(100)
  }
```

Comment: It turns out that I do need it to be something specific, otherwise it might not have the method transform.

Comment: @PaulReiners If you use intellij do `Alt+enter` at the return type of the function and get type information

Comment: @PaulReiners I think the type should be `org.apache.spark.ml.Estimator[DecisionTreeRegressionModel]`

Comment: If I do that, I get this error:

[error]  found   : org.apache.spark.ml.regression.RandomForestRegressor
[error]  required: org.apache.spark.ml.Estimator[org.apache.spark.ml.regression.DecisionTreeRegressionModel]
[error]       .setNumTrees(NumTrees)
[error]                   ^
[error] one error found

Comment: What does this sort of error mean?

[error]  found   : org.apache.spark.ml.regression.RandomForestRegressor
[error]  required: org.apache.spark.ml.Estimator[org.apache.spark.ml.Model[_]]
[error] Note: org.apache.spark.ml.regression.RandomForestRegressionModel <: org.apache.spark.ml.Model[_] (and org.apache.spark.ml.regression.RandomForestRegressor <: org.apache.spark.ml.Estimator[org.apache.spark.ml.regression.RandomForestRegressionModel]), but class Estimator is invariant in type M.
[error] You may wish to define M as +M instead. (SLS 4.5)
[error]       .setNumTrees(NumTrees)

Comment: @PaulReiners You did not post about `setNumTrees` in the question